# Cumulative return in a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a table of daily data in Excel. Let's say it's daily stock return data that looks like:

```
Date,      DailyReturn
1/1/2001,    .021
1/2/2001,    .005
1/3/2001,    .0034
1/4/2001,    .013
....
12/31/2001,  .004
```

The data is in a table on one of the sheets. Let's call it TableOfData. I've added a pivot table on another sheet, and I've added the date as the Row Labels. I've also added grouping by year and month to the rows. Now it is easy to add the average and stddev of the returns for each month, but I would also like the total return for the month, which would be calculated as `Product(DailyReturn + 1) -1`

I can add a calculated field called DailyReturnFactor, which is simply DailyReturn + 1, and I can add the Product of that field to the values and the pivot table shows the return for each month, except that I still need to subtract 1. That is where I'm stuck. Any ideas on if this is possible? The other issue is that I would like to do other sets of calculations as well, e.g. kurtosis.

Note I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: I would have to provide a larger set of data to do that. Here is an example. Let's say there are four days in the month and the DailyReturns are .1, .2, .3. 6, I would like to see
The value of (1.1 * 1.2 * 1.3 * 1.6) -1, i.e. 1.7456 in the summary row for the month.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the issue. Thanks for trying, but I don't think you understand the question. I believe that there is no way to do what I want.